# Running SSIS package on SQL 2014

Tags: sql, ssis

I created a new sql job in SQL2014 with an SSIS package created in SQL 2005. 
The job is failing with this error:

> Source: Ready data to zip Ready data to zip     Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'     at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.b__1a()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSAScriptTask(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

Can you please explain the error? I think I'm missing some files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a longshot, but you may be attempting to run the 32-bit version of DTExec.  By default, it's not installed on a 64-bit machine unless you install the client components - which may mean you have an incomplete installation.

Comment: Thnx! This solved my problem too. "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0"  - sql server 2012   dtsx script could not start because of "use 64" was set to true.