# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error when running script task in SSIS from SSMS scheduled job

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

Here is a summary of my problem:

**Background:**

I have created an SSIS package using SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012. The purpose of the package is to load a flat file into a SQL Server 2014 database. The package runs perfectly when executed manually from Visual Studio on both my PC and the database server. I have created a scheduled job in SSMS to run the package which is running under a proxy account based on my profile.

**Issue:**

The package fails when run from the SSMS job with the following error (this is the job's log entry exported from SSMS):

*03/11/2015 08:17:25,ed_daily_extract,Error,1,CMH-SQL02,ed_daily_extract,Run SSIS package,,Executed as user: CMHC-NT\BERRYDA. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.2000.8 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:17:25 AM  Error: 2015-03-11 08:17:28.11     Code: 0x00000003     Source: Archive Files Archive Files     Description: **There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core** Version=10.0.0.0 Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core Version=10.0.0.0 Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'     at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.b__1a()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSTADenaliScriptProject(XmlElement elemProj IDTSInfoEvents events)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj IDTSInfoEvents events)    WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind failure logging set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.  To turn this feature off remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].  End Error  Error: 2015-03-11 08:17:28.63     Code: 0x00000003     Source: Archive Files      Description: The Script Task is corrupted.  End Error  Error: 2015-03-11 08:17:28.63     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Archive Files      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:17:25 AM  Finished: 8:17:28 AM  Elapsed:  3.047 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:03,0,0,,,,0*

======================================================================

The package runs fine from the scheduled job when I disable my script task, so as far as I can tell this task is causing the issue. The purpose of the script task is to archive old files and it runs fine when executed from Visual Studio, so it is not an issue with the code itself.

**What I have done so far:**

I have attempted to research this issue on the web and have run across similar problems, but no definitive solution. I apologize if I have missed something obvious. An example is this thread:

[Running SSIS package on SQL 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042262/running-ssis-package-on-sql-2014)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Daniel

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified" is the problem.   If it runs in BIDS, that means you can navigate to that file path from your box, with your credentials.   This error means you can't navigate to it from your SSIS box with the Proxy credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. That makes sense, but I am unsure how to fix it. I dropped and recreated my credential and proxy to just to make sure, then I recreated my script task in Visual Studio on the server where it is running fine from VS on that box, but still won't from SSMS. My user ID (which the credential is based on) has access to any of the Visual Studio files on the server.

Comment: Do you have a network admin there you can work with on it?    I don't know how to troubleshoot problems like this on other peoples' networks.   It's not my area of expertise.

Comment: Understood. I'll see if I can work with someone here to track down the issue. Thank you for your help!